# How it is printing 400

Tags: javascript, object

**How it is printing 400**
*I am not able to get it*

```
var a = {},
      b = { key: "b" },
      c = { key: "c" };
      a[b] = 100;
      a[c] = 200;
    
    console.log(a[b] + a[c]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Object keys must be strings (or symbols). When you try to use a non-string, non-symbol as a key with bracket notation, it will be converted into a string first.

`b` and `c` are both objects, so when turned into a string, the result is `[object Object]`. So `a[b]` and `a[c]` refer to the same property on the object. The last assignment was

```
a[c] = 200;
```

so whenever you reference `a[b]` or `a[c]`, that's the value you get. So

```
a[b] + a[c]
```

is just

```
200 + 200
```

because `b` and `c` are the same when converted into a string for a property key.

Comment: While doing this

`b = { "key": b },
  c = { "key": c };`

Or doing this

`b = { "key": 'b' },
  c = { "key": 'c' };`

Also getting 400 as answer

Comment: Yes, because plain objects, no matter what they contain, when turned into strings, give `[object Object]` (as long as they don't contain a custom `toString` method - which they don't in this case)